# Inequality of an Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have, for $ p \geq 1 $ that

\begin{equation}
\left( \sum^\infty_{k=0} |a_k|^p \right)^{1/p} < + \infty
\end{equation}

Is it necessarily true that

\begin{equation}
\sum^\infty_{k=0} |a_k|^p \log|a_k| \leq 0
\end{equation}

Here, for my attempt, I am inclined to say yes. The intuition I have is that under the above condition, we should have that $|a_k| \rightarrow 0$, which thus implies that $ |a_k|^p \log|a_k| \rightarrow 0^-$. If so, how should I go above arguing this rigourously? Thanks!

Comment: You are implicitly assuming $a_k\neq0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

To construct a counterexample, consider the convergent sum $$S =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2\ln(n)}{n^2}$$

Consider now the sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ defined by
$$a_0 = S+3 \quad \text{and} \quad a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \text{ if } n \geq 1$$

Then the series $\sum |a_k|$ converges (here I take $p=1$), but one has
$$\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|\log|a_k| = (S+3) \ln(S+3) - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2\ln(k)}{k^2} > S-S = 0.  $$

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice explicit counterexample

Answer (score 3):

$$x\log x\ge-\frac1e$$ so that $$x^p\log x\ge-\frac{x^{p-1}}e.$$

So it is not difficult to find a general term that makes both series converge (say $a_k=\frac1k$ with $p>2$). The sum of the second will be a finite negative number, which you can easily compensate by increasing $a_0$ to make it positive.

Take $a_0>\dfrac{\zeta(p-1)}e$.